# How to encrypt and decrypt with variables in Python

Tags: python, encryption

My goal is to write a code in Python that do the following:
1.Generate a public key.
2. Hash the public key.
3. Generate a random string.
4. Encrypt & decrypt the random string with the hashed public key.

This is the code I written:

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
import random
import string
import hashlib
import base64
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.kdf.pbkdf2 import PBKDF2HMAC

def encrypt(plaintext, password):
   f = Fernet(base64.urlsafe_b64encode(
       PBKDF2HMAC(algorithm=hashes.SHA256(), length=32, salt=b'abcd', iterations=1000,
                  backend=default_backend()).derive(password.encode())))
   return f.encrypt(plaintext.encode()).decode()

def decrypt(ciphertext, password):
   f = Fernet(base64.urlsafe_b64encode(
       PBKDF2HMAC(algorithm=hashes.SHA256(), length=32, salt=b'abcd', iterations=1000,
                  backend=default_backend()).derive(password.encode())))
   return f.decrypt(ciphertext.encode()).decode()

def randomString(strlength = 16):   #Random code
   letters = string.ascii_letters
   return ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(strlength))

key = RSA.generate(2048)  # Private key creation
code = 'nooneknows'

privatekey = key.exportKey(passphrase=code, pkcs=8)
publickey = key.publickey().exportKey()

result = hashlib.md5(publickey)  #Hashing the Publickey
publickey = result.digest()

Nonce=randomString()  # Creating Nonce

encrypt((str(Nonce)), password=(str(publickey)))  # Encrypting nonce with hashed pub.key
decrypt((str(encrypt)), password=(str(publickey)))

print("This is the decrption", encrypt)
print("This is the decrption", decrypt)
```

When I run it, I get the error:

```
D:\Anaconda3\python.exe C:/Users/AVIV/.PyCharmCE2019.1/config/scratches/test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cryptography\fernet.py", line 87, in _get_unverified_token_data
    data = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(token)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\base64.py", line 133, in urlsafe_b64decode
    return b64decode(s)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\base64.py", line 87, in b64decode
    return binascii.a2b_base64(s)
binascii.Error: Incorrect padding

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/AVIV/.PyCharmCE2019.1/config/scratches/test.py", line 39, in <module>
    decrypt((str(encrypt)), password=(str(publickey)))
  File "C:/Users/AVIV/.PyCharmCE2019.1/config/scratches/test.py", line 21, in decrypt
    return f.decrypt(ciphertext.encode()).decode()
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cryptography\fernet.py", line 74, in decrypt
    timestamp, data = Fernet._get_unverified_token_data(token)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cryptography\fernet.py", line 89, in _get_unverified_token_data
    raise InvalidToken
cryptography.fernet.InvalidToken
```

Is there a way to solve this error? 
My guess, is that the issue is with the decoding and encoding to/from bytes. I tried to decode/encode it many times, but always ended up with an error. 
Also, I guess that it has an issue with the padding, but I couldn't figured how to solve it.
I was thinking, maybe the Fernet encryption isn't the right fit for the goals of my project, maybe I should use other encryption/library?

Comment: Can you provide the full traceback of that error (edit it into the question; don't try putting it in a comment)? Also, there's probably a lot of code you can trim out while still leaving a full example that reproduces the error.

Comment: @glibdud Thanks for the reply. I added the full traceback of the error that I'm receiving. I also tried to shorten it as much as I could. Sorry if it's still too long.

Comment: I think you are mixing up two methods of encryption here. An RSA key pair is used for *asymmetric* encryption, where the sender encrypts data using the receiver's public key, and the receiver decrypts it with their private key. Here you are using Fernet, which does *symmetric* encryption, so the same key is used for encryption and decryption, and this key must be a secret only known by the sender and receiver. It doesn't really make sense for that secret to be based on either person's public RSA key.

Comment: @SamuelRice Thanks for the reply, Samuel. Actually, you are right. If third party user/hacker would gain access to the public key (which is publicly known), he will be able to decrypt the messages, and the connection won't be secured. However, this is just a test project and the error here is with the code himself, my goal is only to encrypt and decrypt a string with the hashed publickey. But you can do the decrpytion with the private key, and then the connection will be secured :)

Answer (score 0):

You are not actually assigning encrypt to a variable, you are sending in an encrypt function as the argument for the decrypt function. Make this change this at the end of your code:

```
encrypted = encrypt((str(Nonce)), password=(str(publickey)))  # Encrypting nonce with hashed pub.key
decrypted = decrypt((str(encrypted)), password=(str(publickey)))

print("This is the encrypted", encrypted)
print("This is the decrypted", decrypted)
```

The output for `decrypted` will be the Nonce that you encrypted.